# update the object in the database to indicate that a payment has been successfully processed

Tags: python, django, mongodb, stripe-payments, webhooks

`

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    time.sleep(30)
    payload = request.body
    signature_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, signature_header, settings.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(f"ValueError: {e}")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        logging.error(f"SignatureVerificationError: {e}")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        session_id = session.get('id', None)    
        if session_id:
            try:
                user_payment = UserPayment.objects.get(stripe_checkout_id=session_id)
                user_payment.payment_bool = True
                user_payment.save()
                logging.info(f"Updated payment_bool for session_id: {session_id}")
            except UserPayment.DoesNotExist:
                logging.error(f"UserPayment not found for session_id: {session_id}")
        else:
            logging.error("session_id is missing in the event data.")
    return HttpResponse(status=200)`
```

I have been trying to update the 'UserPayment' object in the database to indicate that a payment has been successfully processed, but it doesn't work, even though the payment is successful in sripe

Comment: First you need to test your webhook and put logs after the line `if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':`. Stripe has a Doc on how to debug your Webhook https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#test-webhook